# Surface 3 + Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, surface

I am thinking about getting a surface 3 as I cant afford a surface pro 3, and was just wondering if I could run the android emulator on it, from the android sdk, to support my app developments.

I would be greatful for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Surface 3 has an Intel x7 Atom processor, so it will run everything that your Windows desktop would run.

Might I also recommend that you take a look at the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx)? It's fast, free, and uses Hyper-V, so it will work even better with your new Surface 3 :)

Answer (score -1):

The Surface 3 runs a quad core Atom processor. It does not have VT extensions. I tried to run both Andy Android and AMIDuos Android emulators and neither really worked. AMIDuos sorta ran, but it would lock up the whole computer after a while. If this had worked, it would have made the Surface 3 an 11 out of 10 stars. As it stands, it is still a 10.

I was bummed out about this, but all I really wanted to do was to check on a Clash of Clans village every day or two. I can do that on the Andy Android emulator on my laptop and office rig.